# jQuery Cycle (only IE 6-8): nested element disappears during the transition

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cycle, transition, absolute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disappearing images in IE8 jQuery Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196819/disappearing-images-in-ie8-jquery-cycle)

if the nested element positioned absolute outside the parent element, then it disappears during the transition. This effect occurs only in ie browser, ff, safari, chrome does the transition just fine.
any help is appriciated.

```
<div class="conainer">
   <div class="element"><div class="nested"></div></div>
   <div class="element"><div class="nested"></div></div>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question...Like what do you mean by transition actually here....