# Disappearing images in IE8 jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cycle

http://www.lunatestsite.co.uk/products/lifestation

Cannot for the life of me fix this. Only in IE8 so far. I had the same issue on the homepage cycle, but managed to fix by declaring width, height and background: none !important on the img's in question.

I thought it might be a png issue, but the same happens with jpgs:

http://www.lunatestsite.co.uk/test-disappearing-jpgs

Same result: often a flicker of the first of the two images in the slideshow, then disappears.

Any ideas at all appreciated.

SOLVED: My original fix worked for this in the end too : adding the background: none important!, and declaring the width / height. It didn't work on the additional templates because I was using a class instead of id for ul#product-images.

The shame, it burns! Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

```
body.home #front-slider #front-slides .slide{
background:none !important;
width: 980px;
height: 389px;
}

body.home #front-slider #front-slides .slide .slide-image img{
    background:none !important;
    width: 629px;
    height: 345px;
}

body.page-template-page-product-view-php ul#product-images .slide, body.page-template-page-product-view-wide-php ul#product-images .slide{
    background:none !important;
    width: 970px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: CSS3Pie helped stop hating IE: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: How does CSS3Pie help with this? Sorry, don't see the connection.

Comment: css3 pie fixes all kinds of IE8 CSS quirks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having this issue also and I traced it back to the CSS rule

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Once I removed the above rule (I didn't need it in this case) the images stopped disappearing.

Comment: This worked for me. The max-width: 100% was coming from the [1140 grid](http://cssgrid.net/) so I didn't want to remove it beyond the slideshow. I was able to override it with .slide img { max-width: inherit }

Comment: Miraculously, this fixed the problem for me as well. It should be documented somewhere, since `max-width: 100%;` is a common trick to accommodate mobile browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the

```
max-width: 100%;
```

then also add

```
width: auto;
```

OR remove the explicit width and height attributes from the HTML

OR put the image in a non-floated container

OR assign the container a specific width.

There is a pretty good article on this bug here:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201202/using_max-width_on_images_can_make_them_disappear_in_ie8/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the images are still loading.

Try this...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#product-images, #front-slides').cycle({
        timeout: '7000',
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev',
        pager: '#pager',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, el) {
                return '<a href="#"></a>';
            }
    });
 });
```

`window.load()` will fire after the DOM **and** the page's images have loaded, where `document.ready()` only fires after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: IE is fussy as hell with `window.load` too.  Are the images hidden (`display` or `visibility`) in any way before/during the DOM loads?

Comment: The Cycle plugin just directly changes the opacity attribute of the images' parent <li> from 0 to 1, and sets display to either block or none dependent on if it's the current slide.

Comment: I've noticed IE8 will ignore the `window.load()` for images that are hidden or invisible.  They still won't load until they are made visible again.  Let me find my working workaround.

Comment: @luke, sorry, my workaround won't work with Cycle since it's part of my own plugin.  I recommend doing an image pre-load before Cycle is called.  It's ugly but even IE8 will work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

to

```
img {
    max-width: auto;
}
```