# jquery cycle with nested divs not fading in IE8 and earlier

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-cycle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disappearing images in IE8 jQuery Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196819/disappearing-images-in-ie8-jquery-cycle)

I inherited a site that uses the JQuery Cycle plugin. The slideshow is slightly different on the homepage than the inside pages, where the former is merely an img as a child of the parent contained, but the latter is a div as a child of the parent containing several other elements depending on the slide.

Both sliders are working just fine in every browser, except IE8 and below. In that case, the homepage slider is transitioning fine, but the inside pages' slider does not fade out/in, and it's also leaving a time gap between the slides.

The HTML for the slider is:

```
<div id="page-panels">
  <!-- Slide 1 -->
  <div>
    <img class="left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/page-slide-1.jpg"
    alt="protecting and providing for you and your family" width="400" height="180"
    />
    <p class="smaller">"Steven developed a thorough plan to meet our complicated needs with a
      blended family and special needs child in a timely manner."
      <br /><span> - &nbsp;Cheryl F.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 2 -->
  <div>
    <img class="left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/page-slide-2.jpg"
    alt="avoiding estate tax and probate costs" width="400" height="180" />
    <p class="bigger">"Mr. Jackson made a tough process easy and painless!"
      <br /><span> - &nbsp;Kyle M.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 3 -->
  <div>
    <img class="left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/page-slide-3.jpg"
    alt="keeping your estate plan current with the law" width="400" height="180"
    />
    <p class="bigger">"Integrity, trust - a rare item - it's <em>here!</em>"
      <br /><span> - &nbsp;Ron F.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Further down the page is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#page-panels').cycle({
            timeout:    10000,
            speed:        3000,
            slideExpr:     'div'
        });
    });
</script>
```

But that didn't fix it.

Here is the link for the inside pages: http://www.stevenandrewjackson.com/our-unique-estate-planning-process/
Here is the homepage: http://www.stevenandrewjackson.com/

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Both links to your site return 500 internal server errors.